# NavBar Image Links Aren't Working, but code is perfect. What's up?

Tags: html, css, navbar

So here's my current HTML code, within the `<head>` section:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.greg-holmes.com/#/title" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/home.png">
        </a>
    </li>
    ... <!-- Deleted some elements for readability -->
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/djspiffy" target="_blank">
            <img src="img/instagram.png">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS that goes along with it:

```
.nav {
    border-width: 1px 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The code is live at [greg-holmes](http://www.greg-holmes.com), but for some reason the links aren't working.

Comment: You didn't write it yourself, right?

Comment: Yep, I did with the HTML but not the CSS. Why, what do you think is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your HTML code inside `<body>` tag not `<head>` tag

Comment: looking at the source of greg-holmes.com, the HTML is still in the header

Comment: @user2303322 try to put your `ul` with class `nav` inside `div` with id `impress`

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't go in the page header, all HTML belongs in the body.. your code should be

```
<html>

<head>
...
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I updated the code so the HTML is now in the body, but it's still not working. Any thoughts?